# DNS Wildcard entry and specific nested subdomain

Tags: dns

Let's say we have the following two entries in our zonefile for `mydomain.de`

```
*             IN A     35.234.100.200
mytest.test   IN A     35.234.100.201
```

We would now expect that `example.mydomain.de` resolves to `35.234.100.200`.
Instead it **does not resolve to anything**. Why is that?

Note that when we remove the second entry, the wildcard entry does apply and  `example.mydomain.de` resolves to `35.234.100.200`.

---

#### Update:

Our bad. The above shown configuration works as expected. We seem to have seen some other unrelated issue.

Comment: Not sure about the syntax of your example. For BIND compatible zone files If you have a record `*   IN     A   35.234.100.200` in zone file for `mydomain.de` it will act as wild card for all hosts in this domain that have no `A` records.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg you are right, of course and I edited the entries to be correctly formatted. Do they make sense now?

Comment: Yes, it looks correct and should work as expected. I tried such records (with diff names and IPs of course) and it just works.